# How do I access the itemPrice part of this array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I need to grab the itemPrice part of the index and add them all together, but i'm not sure how to go about accessing that. Can I somehow use my getCost method from the GroceryItemOrder class and continuously add it to the totalCost in the GroceryList class, or do I need to access the itemPrice and quantity part of each stored object.

```
public class GroceryList {

    public GroceryItemOrder[] groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[0];
    public int manyItems;


    public GroceryList() {
        final int  INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
        groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        manyItems = 0;
    }

    //Constructs a new empty grocery list array
    public GroceryList(int numItem) {
        if (numItem < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                    ("The amount of items you wanted to add your grocery list is negative: " + numItem);
        groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[numItem];
        manyItems = 0;
    }

    public void add(GroceryItemOrder item) {
        if (manyItems <= 10) {
            groceryList[manyItems] = item;
        }
        manyItems++;
    }

    //
    // @return the total sum list of all grocery items in the list
    public double getTotalCost() {
        double totalCost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++ ) {
            //THIS PART
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

}
```

And this is GroceryItemOrder

```
public class GroceryItemOrder {
    public String itemName;
    public int itemQuantity;
    public double itemPrice;

    public GroceryItemOrder(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) {
        itemName = name;
        itemQuantity = quantity;
        itemPrice = pricePerUnit;
    }

    public double getcost() {
        return (itemPrice*itemQuantity);
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        itemQuantity = quantity;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (itemName + " " + itemQuantity);
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the replies! I got it working and understand what's going on here now.

Comment: Since the instance variables of `GroceryItemOrder` have `public` visibility you don't need to use a method for it. Simply access them using `GroceryItemOrder.itemPrice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to access an instance of `GroceryItemOrder` in the array and from there then access its `itemPrice` field like so,

```
groceryList[0].itemPrice
```

would give you the itemPrice of the first groceryListOrder in the groceryList array. If you want to use a method to do this instead, then add a `getItemPrice` method in your `groceryListOrder` class,

```
public getItemPrice() {
    return itemPrice;
}
```

Then you can access each groceryListOrder's itemPrice in the array like so,

```
groceryList[0].getItemPrice()
```

would do the same as `groceryList[0].itemPrice`. If you wanna get the total cost of all the objects in the `groceryList` array, then use a loop to add all the `itemPrice` fields multiplied by the `itemQuantity` field (since it's the totalcost of each object being summed together) by using your `getcost` method,

```
double totalCost = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
    totalCost += groceryList[i].getcost();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should encapsulate all fields of`GroceryItemOrder` class, so all the fields should be private member of the class and then use their setter/getter methods to access them in `GroceryList`.

Secondly, this implementation has a bug. The second constructor gets `numItem` as input and initialize array size accordingly. But, `add` method does not look at the real size and that might cause invalid array index exception. Consider this code:

```
GroceryList list = new GroceryList(2);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    list.add(new GroceryItemOrder("grocery", 5, 10));
```

The exception will be occurred when `i=2`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you would need to set `static GroceryItemOrder[] groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[0];` as well:

```
//
// @return the total sum list of all grocery items in the list
public static double getTotalCost() {
    double totalCost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++ )
    {
        totalCost += groceryList[i].getcost();
    }
    return totalCost;
}
```